# Websphere 6.1 console empty

Tags: console, websphere

After deploying an application, we've lost access to the Integrated Solution Console of Websphere 6.1

Somehow the menu is completely empty. Only the "welcome" link is showing. We have not security enabled

We restarted the server with no luck

Any idea how this can happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure isclite.ear (adminconsole ) started successfully with no errors in server systemout.log file . If there are no errors in systemOut.log file , run following command and see if that helps:
/WAS_HOME/profiles/profile_name/bin>iscdeploy.sh/bat -restore
Hope this helps . 
Thank you
VTho

Comment: We solve it restoring the correct permission on files as I explain below. However thanks for the hint, it may be useful someday

Answer (score 0):

We solved it. The problem was that somehow we launched the server with root user and it changed some configuration files. One we launched it again with the right user the problem appeared. We did a recursive chmod to set the correct file permissions and it worked fine again.